# Left outer join not bringing nulls

Tags: sql-server, database, join

I have a table of time attendance in a company where the employees' attendance data is stored so for example in the current month the user may have attended in :-
2023-03-01
2023-03-02
2023-03-05
2023-03-06

I want to select `all days of month from the calendar` and join with the attendance table and if there is a match between dates the date from the attendance table is selected and if there is no record on some day, the value should be `null` for example on '2023-03-03' and 2023-03-04'

I have tried with the following code but it doesn't work :-

```
    WITH fnDateNow(DayOfDate) AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(date,dateadd(d,-(day(getdate()-1)),getdate()),106) AS DayOfDate
        UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DayOfDate) FROM fnDateNow WHERE DayOfDate < CONVERT(date,dateadd(d,-(day(dateadd(m,1,getdate()))),dateadd(m,1,getdate())),106)
) SELECT fnDateNow.DayOfDate, dbo.Attendance2023.DayDate AS Expr1    
FROM fnDateNow

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Attendance2023 ON MONTH(fnDateNow.DayOfDate) = MONTH(Attendance2023.DayDate)
AND YEAR(fnDateNow.DayOfDate) = YEAR(Attendance2023.DayDate)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Employee ON dbo.Attendance2023.EmployeeID = dbo.Employee.EmployeeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Level1 ON dbo.Employee.Level1ID = dbo.Level1.Level1ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Level2 ON dbo.Employee.Level2ID = dbo.Level2.Level2ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Level3 ON dbo.Employee.Level3ID = dbo.Level3.Level3ID
  
WHERE dbo.Employee.CompanyCode = @payroll AND MONTH(fnDateNow.DayOfDate) = @Month
ORDER BY DayOfDate
```

I get the following result :-
[image: Result Image]

Comment: `WHERE dbo.Employee.CompanyCode = @payroll` turns your `LEFT JOIN` into an implicit `INNER JOIN`; it is impossible for `NULL = @payroll` to ever be true. The clause should be in the `ON` not the `WHERE`.

Comment: Also, as an FYI, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: I must admit, as well, `fnDateNow`, is an odd choice for a CTE; I thought it was an incorrectly referenced function when I looked at the lower `SELECT` statement, due to it's `fn` prefix.

Comment: There also, on a separate note, a problem of SARGabilty due to clauses like `MONTH(fnDateNow.DayOfDate) = @Month` and `MONTH(fnDateNow.DayOfDate) = MONTH(Attendance2023.DayDate)
AND YEAR(fnDateNow.DayOfDate) = YEAR(Attendance2023.DayDate)`; you should *really* be using date boundaries. That, however, is a different question.

Comment: That is really complicated way to get all the days for a given month. I would suggest looking into using tally tables instead of recursive ctes for things like that.

Comment: To build on @Larnu 's comment: you should use `ON Attendance2023.DayDate >= fnDateNow.DayOfDate AND Attendance2023.DayDate >= DATEADD(month, 1, fnDateNow.DayOfDate)` etc